# glmer fit and quasi-complete separation: no convergence issues, but weirdly low significance value

Tags: lme4, mixed-models

I'm trying to measure performance on a task in which most - but not all - of my participants are perfect. The p value of interest (on the fixed intercept term) seemed implausibly low, so I switched one response to incorrect for each of the perfect participants, and this dramatically increased the significance, even though in the modified data participants are worse! I would think this has something to do with quasi-complete separation (since so many participants are perfect), but I do not get a singular fit warning, and my model converges fine! Here is toy data that replicates the issue:

```
# Data with many participants having perfect performance
tibble(
  id=factor(1:10),
  successes=c(9,7,rep(10,8)),
  trials=10
  ) %>%
  glmer(cbind(successes,trials-successes)~1+(1|id),data=.,family="binomial") %>%
  summary()

# Replacing perfect performance with 90% performance yields a much lower p-value!
tibble(
  id=factor(1:10),
  successes=c(9,7,rep(9,8)),
  trials=10
) %>%
  glmer(cbind(successes,trials-successes)~1+(1|id),data=.,family="binomial") %>%
  summary()
```

How can I get the model to behave with the first dataset? Or would you avoid a glmer in the first place? It seems inappropriate to just pool these into a single binomial test, right?